# knockout computed value of type number returning a concatenated string instead of sum

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

Ex 1:

```
this.total = ko.computed<number>(() =>{
    return this.baseSave() * 1 + (this.ability.modifier() * 1) + this.magic() *1  + this.miscellaneous()* 1 + this.temporary()*1;
});
```

Ex 2:

```
this.total = ko.computed<number>(() =>{
    return this.baseSave() + this.ability.modifier() + this.magic() + this.miscellaneous() + this.temporary();
});
```

I am using knockout with typescript

Given (0,10,0,0,10)

Ex 1 works returning 20, ex 2 fails 0100010 as a string

properties in question are all declared and initialized like

```
export class someClass{
    baseSave: KnockoutObservable<number>;

    constructor(){
        baseSave = ko.observable<number>(0);
    }
}
```

with the exception of ability which is a class that is passes in the constructor of the class holding the computed value.
Any ideas/suggestions on why this is happening?

Comment: you need to use javascript `parseInt()`

Answer (score 2):

When you bind to the UI you get back strings based on what the user types. Multiplying with 1 makes it a number (which is what you think it should be).

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Here's a fiddle demonstrating what happens... http://jsfiddle.net/bjNrV/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is loosely-typed and the '+' operator is overloaded. This means it can be used to add numbers and also concatenate strings. It works out which to do by looking at the type of the arguments.

This is worth a general read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading

In Ex 2, the KO observables are returning strings, so + is working to concatenate the strings.

In Ex 1, the (* 1) casts the string to an int, then + is working to add them.

However, it is a bit more 'proper' to use parseInt, so ideally your code will be:

```
this.total = ko.computed<number>(() =>{
    return parseInt(this.baseSave()) + 
        parseInt(this.ability.modifier()) + 
        parseInt(this.magic()) + 
        parseInt(this.miscellaneous()) + 
        parseInt(this.temporary());
});
```

It's pretty handy to get used to parseInt, because you can use it if you ever need to deal with strings containing binary, etc. Have a read here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

eg

```
parseInt("10")
```

returns an int of 10, because it assumed we're in the decimal system by default, But if you supply a radix of 2:

```
parseInt("10", 2)
```

then 10 is interpreted as binary, and the an int of 2 is returned.